# Pandas Filter Rows based on Date - miffed

Tags: pandas, date, filter

Been working on code to push stock data through some formulas to help pick what I want. To ensure formulas work, would like to back test (simulate) what the formula would have predicted. Original data table rows run from 2009-1-1 to 2019-12-2, and columns company 1, company 2 etc ( 99 compares)

I make seperate tables in Excel ie from 2009-1-1 to 2018-10-1 and run it through python -  and then see ie 2018-11-1 what the outcome would be. Results I am happy with..... ie 22% returns, but I have cut the input data manually

Thought it would be simple to automate ( cut the raw data in DF's and feed it in the model ).

Problem is, the data gets all jumbled up and I have tried so many options, and still cant figure out why. read almost every thread on the topic.  Would appreciate advice.

seems so silly, but I am miffed

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from datetime import date, timedelta

#read stock_price.csv file and sort by date
df_price = pd.read_csv("tests/stock_prices.csv")
df_price['date']= pd.to_datetime(df_price['date'])
#df_price.set_index('date', drop=True, append=False, inplace=True, verify_integrity=False)

#this is where it goes wrong
df_price_filter = df_price[df_price["date"].isin(pd.date_range("2009-01-01", "2018-09-28"))]
df_price_filter.sort_values(by='date')

print(df_price_filter)
pd.DataFrame(df_price_filter).to_csv('CGResults/5_data_2018-09_28.csv',index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
start_date = "2009-01-01"
end_date = "2018-09-28"
date_filter = (df_price["date"] >= start_date) & (df_price["date"] <= end_date)
df_price_filter = df_price[date_filter]
df_price_filter = df_price_filter.sort_values(by='date')
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind advice..... the date field imports from excel as a "object", so I need to add df_price['date']= pd.to_datetime(df_price['date']) to convert it to datetime64[ns]. (other wise filter won't find dates to filter ) --- good news is the filter works. BUT, when apply the sort -df_price_filter = df_price_filter.sort_values(by='date')- , I get the same results, various fields in the columns get jumbled up. could it be my save ? not sure if the save or the sort code is the culprit.

Comment: Interestingly - I just deleted the sort code, then ran it , and manually sorted the excel output. Also jumbled. so I feel the filter code is the root cause.   Another note, the jumbled data seems to be consistent though with certain NaN fields being filled in same pattern

Comment: ... stay tuned....  deleted almost all code to track down the elusive enemy.....   feel its got to do with the date formats dd/mm. vs mm/dd. Excel file is dd/mm/yyyy format, but I believe the conversion of dates with df_price['date']= pd.to_datetime(df_price['date'] converts those wrongly to mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Closed.... worked 2 days on it. Basically pd.Datetime is a very very temperamental young girl.... new learning. answer was       df_price['date']= pd.to_datetime(df_price['date'], format ='%d-%b-%y')